# How to link my Flask Server running on a specific port to a domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a flask application running on an EC2 AWS Windows server instance on port 5000. I have just bought a domain name on 123-reg.co.uk and would like to use that domain name to access my server publicly. I can access my application by navigating to the public ip and port 5000, but I would like to use the domain name (and for it appear in the address bar)

Honestly I am stuck on where to go with this!.

Comment: The cheapest way to do this would be to simply change your application's port from `5000` to `80` which is the default HTTP port, or `443` for HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do:
You install an actual production server like Nginx on the EC2 instance. Then you point your domain to IP address to that. Nginx acts as a proxy server to your flask server on port 5000.
Note: Nginx runs on port 80 anyways, so just point domain to IP address in your DNS.